# Why does the Big O notation of summation give log

Tags: real-analysis, summation, logarithms, asymptotics, computer-science

I’m not understanding the following line in a proof[image]

I believe it should be $O(h^2\psi(2h))$ since $\sum_{j=1}^{h}\frac{1}{j}\leqslant h\cdot1=h$

Comment: Looks like it's because of the harmonic sum https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)

Comment: It is true that $s_{h}=O(h^{2}\psi(2h))$, but $O(h\psi(2h)\log(h))$ is a valid bound that is tighter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $=O$ needs to be discouraged; it should be $\in O$. It's also important to note $o(f(h))\subseteq O(f(h))$, so very different looking arguments can go in the $O$. In this example,$$\sum_{j=1}^h\frac1j\sim\int_1^h\frac1JdJ=\ln h\in O(\ln h)\subseteq o(h)\subseteq O(h).$$

Comment: What is the difference between o and O?

Comment: @Jaunemoto Compare [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition).

Comment: Thank you. In the second link they use equals instead of $\in$ as well. Is that old notation?

Comment: @Jaunemoto I don't know what came first (though I think it's $\in$), but in our modern understanding [$=$ is lazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation).

Answer (score 2):

You found the correct statement

$$\sum_{j=1}^h \frac1j \in O(h).$$

The authors of the paper used the correct statement

$$\sum_{j=1}^h \frac1j \in O(\log h),$$

as explained in the answer by Parcly Taxel. Since $\log h \in o(h)$, the paper uses the sharper, "better" bound. Yours isn't wrong, it's just not as good as could be.

You can find details about why $\sum_{j=1}^h \frac1j \in O(\log h)$ in the wikipedia entry for the [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: Thanks for explaining this

Answer (score 1):

This is but a harmonic series summation:
$$\sum_{j=1}^h\frac{2h\psi(2h)}j=2h\psi(2h)\sum_{j=1}^h\frac1j\in2h\psi(2h)\cdot O(\log h)\sim O(h\psi(2h)\log h)$$

Comment: Why is the order of the series log(h)?

Comment: @Jaunemoto It just is... you are supposed to learn this by heart. It can be derived from approximating $\int1/x\,dx$ with a Riemann sum.